# Highlight few points in plot

Tags: r, plot

I try to plot the following data with few positions (points) to highlight

```
plot(b$pos,b$log_p,col==ifelse(b$pos==c(14824849,13920386,14837470),90,100), pch=19, xlab='Chromosome 21 position', ylab='-log10(p)')
```

The plot produced, only show one point highlighted red with the following warning message:

```
In b$pos == c(14824849, 13920386,14837470) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Are you trying to highlight positions is in c(14824849,13920386,14837470),90,100)?

Comment: Yes, the position are c(14824849,13920386,14837470) while 90 and 100 are the colour of the dots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, the issue is likely to be your condition in the ifelse. If you attempt the condition (`b$pos==c(14824849,13920386,14837470)`) outside of your ifelse() you will get an error message along the lines of:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

If you change the condition to:

`b$pos %in% c(14824849,13920386,14837470)`

You will get a vector of TRUE/FALSE values determining whether each entry in b$pos is present in the vector (14824849,13920386,14837470) rather than whether the entries in b$pos are equal to c(14824849,13920386,14837470).

```
x = c(49, 7, 66, 51, 43, 70, 35, 53, 6, 29)
y = c(10, 98, 44, 31, 37, 14, 64, 84,  4, 34)
x %in% c(6, 7)
```

> `[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`

```
plot(x, y, col=ifelse(x %in% c(6, 7), 'red', 'blue'))
```

> [image]

Now this dataset has 10 `x` values, if you were to write this:

```
plot(x, y, col=ifelse(x == c(1, 7), 'red', 'blue'))
```

This would work fine,  the x values would be compared against 1 and 7 alternately e.g:

```
49 == 1 ?
7 == 7 ?
66 == 1?
51 == 7? .... etc etc.
```

The error message was saying that your vector length of 3 did not exactly go into the length of the b$pos.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `tidyverse` and `ggplot` you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = c(49, 7, 66, 51, 43, 70, 35, 53, 6, 29),
y = c(10, 98, 44, 31, 37, 14, 64, 84,  4, 34),
gr=x %in% c(6, 7)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y, col=gr)) + 
   geom_point(size=2) + 
   ggalt::geom_encircle(data= . %>% filter(gr), color="green", s_shape=0) +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Using `ggalt::geom_encircle` function you can draw a circle around your points of interest.